# Huge number of missed chats

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, embedded-services

My org runs an embedded service deployment for live chat. We're seeing enormous numbers of missed chats (thousands per month)  and we're struggling to understand why. Missed chats are also being recorded when the form is in an offline state with no pre-chat form showing.

Has anyone come across this issue before and are there any starting points for investigation that should typically be followed?

Comment: Just for complete undertanding. What did call MISSED CHATS? 1 - You can't start chat with your agent
2 - During chat you lost connection
3 - Other thing Do you have BOT for first contact with customer or when customer starts a conversation this interaction is directly with your agent?

Comment: @Carlos Carvalho - looks like a number of reasons from the report I'm looking at. Visitor left chat appears to be the biggest reason, but I can't see how this would be in scenarios where the chat button is in an offline state with no pre-chat form. There's no bot in place so the conversation is directly with the agent.